# Limiting options after user chooses option (HTML)

Tags: html, css, flask

As of right now, I have two lists of options to choose from for a form in HTML. However, choosing a value in one list would make certain options in the second list impossible. Specifically, the first list is a list of possible units (cm, in, ft.), while the second is a list of locations. Choosing a unit  would limit the number of possible locations that would have this unit. Similarly, choosing a country value would limit the number of units that are available. Would it be possible in any way to limit the choices available to the user after they select either a location or a unit?

```
Unit:
<br>
<select name="unit_input">
    <br>
    <option selected disabled hidden></option>
    <option value="l">League</option>
    <option value="m">Mile</option>
    <option value="ft">Foot</option>
    <option value='m'>Meter</option>
    <option value="st">Stage</option>
    <option value="km">Kilometer</option>
</select>
<br>

Location:
<br>
<select name="nationality_input">
    <br>
    <option selected disabled hidden></option>
    <option value="italian">Italian</option>
    <option value="german">German</option>
    <option value="french">French</option>
    <option value="hungarian">Hungarian</option>
    <option value="british">British</option>
    <option value="swiss">Swiss</option>
    <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: It's possible, yes. You can adjust your HTML with JavaScript, hooking onto `change` events to test the selected value in one `<select>` to display/hide `<option>`s in the next.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using JavaScript: https://codepen.io/dpamonty/pen/PoqRZQd

(Don't forget to add ID to your drop-down list for the code to work).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Unit:
        <br>
        <select id="unit_input" name="unit_input" onchange="restrictDropDownLists()">
            <br>
            <option selected disabled hidden></option>
            <option value="l">League</option>
            <option value="m">Mile</option>
            <option value="ft">Foot</option>
            <option value='m'>Meter</option>
            <option value="st">Stage</option>
            <option value="km">Kilometer</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        Location:
        <br>
        <select id="nationality_input" name="nationality_input" onchange="restrictDropDownLists()">
            <br>
            <option selected disabled hidden></option>
            <option value="italian">Italian</option>
            <option value="german">German</option>
            <option value="french">French</option>
            <option value="hungarian">Hungarian</option>
            <option value="british">British</option>
            <option value="swiss">Swiss</option>
            <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function restrictDropDownLists(){
                var unit = document.getElementById("unit_input");
                var nationalilty = document.getElementById("nationality_input");

                switch(unit.value){
                    case "m":
                        // Options to hide:
                        nationalilty.options[1].style.display = "none"; // Italian
                        // etc.
                        // Options to show:
                        nationalilty.options[4].style.display = ""; // British
                        // etc.
                        break;
                    // etc.
                }

                switch(nationalilty.value){
                    case "british":
                        // Options to hide:
                        unit.options[6].style.display = "none"; // Kilometer
                        // etc.
                        // Options to show:
                        unit.options[1].style.display = ""; // League
                        // etc.
                    // etc.
                }
            }

            // Restrict on the page load as well:
            restrictDropDownLists();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to do this with pure CSS with something like:

```css
#second option { display: none; }
#first:has(> option#a:checked) ~ #second option.a { display: block; }
#first:has(> option#b:checked) ~ #second option.b { display: block; }
#first:has(> option#c:checked) ~ #second option.c { display: block; }
```

```html
<select id="first">
  <option id="a">a</option>
  <option id="b">b</option>
  <option id="c">c</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
  <option class="a b c">Shown for all options</option>
  <option class="a">Shown when a selected</option>
  <option class="c">Shown when c selected</option>
</select>
```

However, [nothing supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility) `:has()` yet. With a change of implementation, you can do something similar in pure CSS. Although, it is far far better to go the JavaScript route; as the following has a number of caveats:

```css
label:after { content: ''; display: block; }
input[name=second] { display: none; }
input[name=second] + label { display: none; }
#a:checked ~ input[name=second].a { display: inline; }
#a:checked ~ input[name=second].a + label { display: inline; }
#b:checked ~ input[name=second].b { display: inline; }
#b:checked ~ input[name=second].b + label { display: inline; }
#c:checked ~ input[name=second].c { display: inline; }
#c:checked ~ input[name=second].c + label { display: inline; }
```

```html
<h4>First</h4>
<input id="a" type="radio" name="first" /><label>A</label>
<input id="b" type="radio" name="first" /><label>B</label>
<input id="c" type="radio" name="first" /><label>C</label>
  
<h4>Second</h4>
<input id="d" type="radio" name="second" class="a b c" /><label>Shown for all options</label>
<input id="e" type="radio" name="second" class="a" /><label>Shown when a is selected</label>
<input id="f" type="radio" name="second" class="c" /><label>Shown when c is selected</label>
```

The major issue with the above is that in order to rely on the [`~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) selector, all the inputs have to be a sibling. So this greatly impacts your layout, and what you can actually achieve. Once `:has()` is supported, pure CSS options will exist, but even then you typically want more logical handling than CSS can offer i.e. how do you allow a user to leave and return to the same point in the form? Or, what happens to selected option's value when it disappears? This is where JavaScript will definitely win out.

Forms are a perfect example of how building a UI (user interface) based upon a state tree is a good idea. This tends to be the focus of frameworks like React, or Vue. Where, depending on the current "state" (an object tree that describes chosen options) the UI just "reacts" and hides/shows conditional elements. To read about this from a pure "state" perspective, looking into [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux) or similar technologies as a basis for what you are building could be good idea.